# "Authentication required. System policy prevents WiFi scans" in FocalFossa

Tags: authentication

For those of you bothered by the deluge of annoying popups asking to authenticate pretty much every move one makes in Focal Fossa ("System policy prevents this and that" when mucking about in WiFi Settings, "Authentication needed to refresh system repositories" etc.), a partial answer is here: https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=14051.

Apparently this is due to **manually installing the xRDP package** in Ubuntu.

Now, if only someone could post the fix for getting rid of network and WiFi-related "Authorization Required" messages, that'd be swell! I am guessing it'd have to be another .pkla file in /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d

Answer (score 13):

It **would not be recommended** to change your network setting while connected through xRDP. If something goes wrong, you will loose your xrdp connection and you will need to logon locally to check your settings.

In practice, yes, you could create a pkla file (under **/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local-d**)  and populate it with the following info...

```
[Allow Wifi Scan]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.scan;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-wifi;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.own;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system;org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes
```

As you can see, the pkla file does a little bit more than authorizing Wifi Scans...Please adapt as required

Hope this help
Till next time
See ya

Comment: I created a file scan.pkla under above mentioned directory and the message disapeared. Thank you Griffon

Comment: thx -- also for scan disable purposes - is enough `org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.scan`

Comment: When using x2go to connect, this other related pkla goes hand in hand: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/417906/authentication-is-required-to-create-a-color-profile

Answer (score 0):

If you're experiencing issues with authorization messages for WiFi and network settings in a remote desktop environment, a script I developed might help. **PolkitFullAccessSetup.sh** automates the creation of Polkit rules, granting full access to specified users or groups. This can effectively bypass the authorization messages you're encountering.

Here’s how it works:

1. The script asks for a username and an optional group name.
2. It creates a Polkit rule granting full access to these specified
   entities.
3. The changes are applied, and the Polkit service is restarted.

Find the script and detailed instructions at: https://github.com/GabrielRamirez/Raspbian-Remote-Polkit-FullAccess

**Note:** This script grants extensive permissions and should be used with caution. It's more suitable for controlled environments and not recommended for general use on production systems.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your user account is a member of the necessary groups to access WiFi features. The primary group is usually netdev.

You can add your user to this group using the following
command: `sudo usermod -aG netdev $USER`

After adding your user to the group, log out and log back in or restart your system for the changes to take effect.